# Try DHCP first, if it fails assign static address and use the machine as a DHCP server itself

Tags: networking, server, dhcp, interface, router

As the title says, I have a tiny screenless Ubuntu server that I move around, that has two different behaviors and needs to adapt automatically, that is, without any human intervention, at bootstrap:

- Tries getting an IP address via DHCP for eth0. If the operation is successful, that's it.
- If obtaining the IP address via DHCP fails, it means that the machine will have to behave as a DCHP server itself, and provide services to other machines connected on its eth0. In addition, it'll have to run a script (which I already have) that configures IP forwarding to make the server a router, as well.

I can't make the various pieces (`/etc/network/interfaces` and the config files of `isc-dhcp-server`) to work together to achieve the above goal, if at all possible.